# About saving Unicode text into mssql database

Tags: php, sql-server, actionscript-3, sql-server-2008, unicode

I have a flash application that communicates with php to save data to nvarchar(1200) column. However when I change to different language support i.e locale, and type into the flash app the letters are good but in the db they are saved as question marks instead of the reall letters.

How can I solve this problem?

How to save the real letters in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database may not be configured to use UTF-8 encoding. SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000 use a different Unicode encoding (UCS-2) and do not recognize UTF-8 as valid character data.

Other versions of mssql may be similar.

See this for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580

If that's not the issue, backtrack to PHP and test the encoding type on the data you are receiving. Make sure it matches what needs to be in your DB, or convert it first.